# Restrict React Router for one time

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In my ReactJS project a link will be opened with some unique id `.../connect/123456` By opening this user can have video call with someone. This is working but the problem is if copy the link and open in a new tab or new browser it still works. What I need is an error message says "Connection already made". How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this server side. Simply have a flag on your database that the call is already in progress. On the front-end side, simply fetch this flag from the database, if call is already in progress: then display the error message and redirect as necessary.

Comment: will give a try